# UNITY: sky showing through building when in play

Tags: unity-game-engine

For a class assignment I have been asked to import a building I have made into Unity. Everything looks fine until I try to play. The sky keeps showing through the building. As you can see in [the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60qwI.png) that circle of sky is not supposed to be there, as I haven't used Unity before I am unsure of how to fix it.

If someone could help me that would be great. 
Thanks.
[image: camera settings]
This is what it looks like in scene
[image: scene]
[image: gameview]

Comment: It sounds like there could be something up with the far clipping plane, which is a property on your camera which you can adjust in the inspector.

Comment: Can you provide a small project with a demo scene that reproduce this issue?

Comment: just added a picture of the settings. thanks

Comment: Could you show how the Scene view and Game view look like before you play.

Comment: i added them. thanks

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't the FPSController prefab have a camera?  It looks like maybe you have 2 cameras in your screen and when you play you get the other...

Comment: Thank you so much i didnt know the Fps controller had a camera.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, this problem could be fixed by increasing the far clipping plane of the Camera.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying  i tried that but it does not change anything the sky is still showing.

Comment: @LauraP Is it showing less if you increase the distance? Is there any change at all?

Comment: no changes at all. i increased it to 6800 and still nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

If the "far" property did not helped, it should be because of the normals.

Lets take the plane object in Unity. One of the face is visible and other side is not.

Similar thing happened to me before. I've made a house model in sketchup. I could see all the walls, from inside and outside. And then i import it into Unity. It seemed nice but when i entered the house, there was nothing. I saw the sky just like you. What i did was, opened the model in SketchUp and add materials to those "invisible" faces.

I am not an expert on normals but Unity sometimes do not render objects without a material on them if they are imported from other sources.

So you can open your model in Blender,SketchUp or other modeling programs and add materials to those invisible surfaces.

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If any of the above answers do not work - it may have to do with your shader and transparencies.  That can sometimes cause issues with front planes dissappearing and showing the back plane.  If it is the case - try changing it to cutout instead in blending mode inside the shader.